# How to replace duplicated columns with a foreign key?

Tags: sql, python-3.x

Given that I have the following tables (datasets) made by python:

```
import pandas as pd

dic ={

    "ID":[1,2,3],
    "patient_ID":[100,200,300],
    "Year":[2007,2008,2012],
    "month":[8,6,3]
}

paitent = pd.DataFrame(dic)
```

So the paitent table is:

```
  ID  patient_ID  Year  month
   1         100  2007      8
   2         200  2008      6
   3         300  2012      3
```

and then the other table has the same columns `patient_ID`, `Year` and the `month`. These 3 columns are duplicated from `patient` table.

```
dic ={

    "patient_ID":[100,200,100,300],
    "Year":[2007,2008,2007,2012],
    "month":[8,6,8,3],
    "Polyp":[4,5,6,8]
}

paitentPolyp = pd.DataFrame(dic)
```

So, it is its final look of `paitentPolyp`

```
  patient_ID  Year  month  Polyp
         100  2007      8      4
         200  2008      6      5
         100  2007      8      6
         300  2012      3      8
```

The question is:

**How may i obtain a view from** `paitentPolyp` **which instead of**  `patient_ID`, `Year` and the `month`  **only has the ID of** `paitent`?

So, my favorit output is:

```
  patient_ID  Polyp
           1      4
           2      5
           1      6
           3      8
```

Although, i am working with python, but a `SQL` solution is more welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In Python:**

```
p = paitentPolyp.merge(paitent, on = ['patient_ID', 'Year', 'month'], how = 'left')
p = p.drop(['patient_ID', 'Year', 'month'], axis =1)
p = (p[['ID', 'Polyp']]).sort_values('ID')
```

**In SQL:**

```
CREATE TABLE patient(
ID int,
patient_id INT,
Years INT,
months int
);

CREATE TABLE patientpoly(
patient_id int,
Years INT,
months INT,
polyp int
);

INSERT INTO patient VALUES(1, 100, 2007, 8);
INSERT INTO patient VALUES(2, 200, 2008, 6);
INSERT INTO patient VALUES(3, 300, 2012, 3);
INSERT INTO patientpoly VALUES(100, 2007, 8, 4);
INSERT INTO patientpoly VALUES(200, 2008, 8, 5);
INSERT INTO patientpoly VALUES(100, 2007, 8, 6);
INSERT INTO patientpoly VALUES(300, 2012, 8, 8);

SELECT patient.ID, patientpoly.polyp
FROM patient
JOIN patientpoly ON patient.patient_id = patientpoly.patient_id
ORDER BY patient.id;
```

Gives the following output:

```
ID      polyp
1         4
1         6
2         5
3         8
```

Comment: @Jeff, let me know if there is any mistake or if the answer doesn't work

Comment: in python solution you have join on `['patient_ID', 'Year', 'month']` but in sql solution you only join the `patient_ID` and it still works well. Could you please explain it?

Comment: I suggest you try running `p = paitentPolyp.merge(paitent, on = ['patient_ID'], how = 'left')` and see the result. Then you'll get a better understanding as to why I used `['patient_ID', 'Year', 'month']`

Comment: sql doesn't create the problem because we are speicifically mentioning the columns we want to obtain after joining the 2 tables

Answer (score 1):

I think you need:

```
new_df = paitent.merge(paitentPolyp, on=["patient_ID", "Year","month"], how="outer")[["ID", "Polyp"]]
```

Output:

```
    ID  Polyp
0   1   4
1   1   6
2   2   5
3   3   8
```

Comment: could you please write the sql solution as well?

Comment: @Jeff Sorry... I am no expert in SQL. The question was intially tagged for python that's why I posted the answer.